# PostgreSQL: How to list the comments attached to a database

Tags: postgresql, metadata

How do I display the comments associated with a database, not a table? I've tried \dd and \list , but can't seem to find this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I looks like this has been already answered on SE network. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493978/how-to-retrieve-the-comment-of-a-postgresql-database)

In particular, note that the question mentions `\l+` in `psql`.